# When to layout subviews programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been porting code from iOS to Android which in iOS used the layoutSubviews method. They worked at first fine, but I am now running into the UIThread becoming blocked with recursive layout loops. The code is btw all done with RelativeLayout using width, height, leftMargin, and rightMargin. I thought that was the best correspondence to CGRect.

Now, I am doing "layoutSubviews" inside of onLayout or an onLayoutChange listener, but I am getting errors like this:

```
03-14 12:10:33.843 31568-31568/----- W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by TextView{17e3bde3 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-200,200} during layout: running second layout pass
```

How can I fix or debug this issue? The thread starts calling layouts of TextView persistently from inside layout traversals, then finally crashes, at which point I can use the app (takes 8 seconds).

The code in general is too complicated to post here, as it works on a small scale OK with small layouts, but fails in the larger layout.

UILabel btw is a an Android TextView extension. Just has a shortcut to setting the font and layoutparams.
[image]

Comment: So you are trying to make a custom textview?

Comment: No. UILabel is just a different name. Also removes padding on init. I am trying to "layout subviews".

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying how much there is a lack of precise knowledge of Android both in the official docs and in these forums. Granted, experts are likely working and Google is too busy. There's only one Sherlock Holmes in each century, so I suppose it is too much to ask.

The problem was solved by using Linear layout for those aspects of the view which were linear in nature ie. in rows, and the relative layouts inside the rows. The problem is that RelativeLayout calls super requestLayout every time a subview's frame is changed, resulting in an infinite loop. How that ever works is beyond me, but all loads quickly now.